# Design patterns in a reporting solution

Tags: c#, design-patterns, mvvm, reporting, telerik-reporting

I'm creating a web reporting solution and was trying to adapt the graphics from Telerik. I realized there always is an option of MVVM design pattern in the list of examples they have. Is there a list of preferred design patterns for a [web] reporting solution?

More detail: I'm looking for programming design patterns to use before I dive into coding. and by reporting solution I mean the sole purpose of this solution is to show interactive graphs online. which will be used in mobile apps later too. I'm planning to use .NET C# to write this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of available resources to start:

- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301852.aspx)
- [The 23 GoF](http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns)
- To avoid duplicate with other answers - [Head First Design Patterns - code samples](http://hfpatternsincsharp.codeplex.com/)
- [Codeplex](https://csharpdesignpatterns.codeplex.com/)

And if you want a piece of advice - look at already developed tools about

> and by reporting solution I mean the sole purpose of this solution is to show interactive graphs online.

like:

- [Open Source Charting & Reporting Tools](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/charting-and-reporting)
- [WINWARD](http://go.windward.net/BizReporting8.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=CPC&utm_term=c%23%20reporting%20tools&utm_id=WR315001&gclid=Cj0KEQjwiJiiBRDh3Z-ctPfS5MgBEiQAAlkbQjCgv_ZHdVuL42pQNilET_jxzfniXdZW-Jt5I1h8AjsaAtR08P8HAQ)
- [DaveChart](http://www.csharpopensource.com/csharpreportingtool/)

Answer (score 2):

Head First Design Patterns or the Gang of Four books are great for learning more about design patterns, though whether they apply to your situation strongly depends on what you are building.